# How to run celery worker in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, celery

I have upgraded Django from version 1.7 to version 1.11.2 and Celery from version 3.1.25 to version 4.0.1.

Before this upgrade I was able to run celery workers throw `django-celery` package in this way:

```
python manage.py celery worker -Q <my_queue> --app=proj.celery:app --concurrency=5
```

Reading Celery release notes and documentation, I found out that for using Django ORM as a result backend, I can't use anymore `django-celery` package but I have to use `django-celery-results` and `django-celery-beat`, instead of it.

With the same command I'm not able to run workers anymore. 
More in detail I try to run the following command:

```
celery worker -app=proj.celery:app -l info
```

Where celery is the celery.exe file in my virtualenv (virtual_env_name\Scripts\celery.exe).

This raised the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
 File "c:\python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\virtualenv\<virtual_env_name>\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "path\of\my\project\celery.py", line 8, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

I tried to import celery directly from the command line, and works well. The problem is raised when I run the command

**celery.py file**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
import django

django.setup()

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**project structure**

```
- main
    - proj
        - __init__.py
        - setting.py
        - celery.py
- manage.py
```

I'm running Python2.7 and Windows 32.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From [Celery 4 documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html#removed-features):

> Microsoft Windows is no longer supported.
>
> The test suite is passing, and Celery seems to be working with Windows, but we make no guarantees as we are unable to diagnose issues on this platform. If you are a company requiring support on this platform, please get in touch.

Unfortunately, it's no longer possible to run celery worker on Windows. You have to stay with 3.1.x versions...

Comment: yes, I have read it, but seems that it's not supported but the test suite is passed..

Comment: Actually, I have no problem to import Celery 4 on Windows, but I have issues with billiard and ampq (See this: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4082) Anyway, for now, it's very difficult to use celery 4 on Windows, so as long as it's not fixed / patched / forked, you should stick to celery 3

Comment: Thanks for the link! Anyway, if I try to import celery from command line (the 
 virtualenv's python) works well. The problem raised when I run the celery command...

Comment: I use a celery.py similar to yours, but with python 3, and the import succeed. Maybe you could remove the absolute_import which seems useless in that case, but i'm not sure. Maybe somebody else will have a better idea